# Oracle to SQL Server (SSIS) special character problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis-2012

I am trying to import data from Oracle to SQL Server through SSIS package data flow task.
One column has special characters and that column is also part of composite key in that table.
So after loading the data on SQL when I am trying to enforce the uniqueness it fails as while loading the data the special characters are getting converted to something else.
Is there any property or alternative so that the special characters are imported the way they are in Oracle.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the datatype on SQL Server that you are importing to?   It needs to be NVARCHAR.

Comment: The datatype on Oracle in VARCHAR2(4 Byte) and I am defining it as NVARCHAR(4 Byte)

Comment: sample :: there is a data where the last charecter is ASCII(137)  but when I am checking the same in sql after loading its converted to ASCII(63)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common issue from my experience.
I will try to describe some steps that might help you.
First, you need to disable the primary key column and run the dtsx again.
Second, you must locate the identical values which cause the primary key violation.
This means that two different chars are mapped to the same char probably and produces the error.

Take in mind that SSIS cannot read with UTF-8 from Oracle, you can see it for your self if you go to Advanced View in Oracle Source Object and inspect the input/output columns, usually, the code page is 1251.

The only solution is to use a Derived Column and replace the problematic character manually before the insert. Also, it will help more if you do this solution.

OracleDB->File->Derived Column->SQLServer